# Bucklescript is compiling utf8 ReasonML files into us-ascii

Tags: unicode, ocaml, reason, bucklescript

I'm using `ReasonReact` with `bsb -init myapp -theme react-hooks`. I run my project on MacOS Catalina. When building or starting my project, `Bucklescript` is compiling my `utf8` `*.re` files into `us-ascii`. This results into bad encoded accentuated characters. I cannot figure out why. Thanks for helping me out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not clear from the question whether you use unicode characters only in string literals, or in identifiers.

If the former, BuckleScript provides syntax for [unicode string literals](https://bucklescript.github.io/docs/en/common-data-types#unicode-support), which should be translated correctly:

```
let unicode = {js|你好， 世界|js};
```

If you use unicode in identifiers, however, the compiler unfortunately does not support that. It's an internal limitation inherited from the OCaml compiler.

Comment: I was looking for `{j|utf string here|j}`. Found ith thanks.

Comment: Unicode in identifiers can be a mixed blessing. E.g. here's a list of visually similar but syntactically invalid Unicode graphemes that the Rust compiler has to know about in case people try to use them in source code: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/b43eb4235ac43c822d903ad26ed806f34cc1a14a/src/libsyntax/parse/lexer/unicode_chars.rs